# How can I find all solution of this equation on $C$?

Tags: complex-numbers

In real number field $\mathbb{R}$, we usually use the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=0$$to show all $x_i$ are zero,

If we can find complex number solution of it?

When $i=1,2$ , the result is normal, I want to know how to solve it when $n\geq3$.

Thank you for sharing your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange the equation to
$$x_1^2 = \sum_{i=2}^n x_i^2$$
Now it is easy to see that you can choose any values you like for $x_2, \dots, x_n$ and then get one or two matching values for $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

***HINT***

Let $z_n=x_n+iy_n$.

We wish to solve: $\sum_{r=1}^{n}z_i^2=0$

We have: $$w=\sum_{r=1}^{n}z_i^2=\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r+iy_r)^2=\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r^2+2ix_ry_r-y_r^2)=\\\sum_{r=1}^{n}x_r^2+\sum_{r=1}^{n}2ix_ry_r-\sum_{r=1}^{n}y_r^2=\\\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r^2-y_r^2)+\sum_{r=1}^{n}2ix_ry_r=\\\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r^2-y_r^2)+2i\sum_{r=1}^{n}x_ry_r=0$$

So, $$w=0\Rightarrow \Re(w)=\Im(w)=0\Rightarrow\\\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r^2-y_r^2)=2i\sum_{r=1}^{n}x_ry_r=0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks,but last should get $$\\\sum_{r=1}^{n}(x_r^2-y_r^2)=0$$  $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}x_ry_r=0$$,if regard it as two vectors, are equal length and vertical.

Comment: @kaixiangchen My mistake. Thank you for noticing. I edited it out.